# Reading from ZlibStream over NetworkStream giving blocking problems in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, compression, zlib, networkstream

I have a network stream over TCP which is a `Zlib` stream in both ways (client to server and server to client).

For `Zlib`, I am using the latest `Ionic.Zlib.dll`.

For the first couple packets that get sent/received, it works fine, but when receiving the 3rd packet or so, it starts misbehaving.

Every read operation on the `ZlibStream` blocks until the packet is repeated by the other end.

For example:

```
// Where reader is a BinaryReader on the ZlibStream on the NetworkStream
int a = reader.ReadInt32(); // blocks until initial packet that is 12 bytes is received
int b = reader.ReadInt32(); // blocks until the packet is repeated
int c = reader.ReadInt32(); // blocks until the packet is repeated again
```

After that code, the packet has actually been sent 3 times and received only once.

Why is it blocking there? How can I get it to not block and continue as expected?

Could flushing in Zlib have anything to do with it? (The stream is flushed after every packet.)

Comment: It'd help if your posted more code. You're using blocking reads here, consider refactor your code to use async/await patterns and async reads (i.e., ReadInt32Async).

Comment: Reading asynchronously won't solve my problem.

Comment: I meant both reads and writes - both ends, so there are no blocks.

Comment: It seems like the unnecessary blocking by the socket is due to the `ZlibStream` layer in between, not the actual socket itself. I don't see how calling both reads and writes asynchronously is going to fix anything. Unless you misunderstood my question. ;)

Comment: If you would rather blame `ZlibStream`, try replacing it with (say) `MemoryStream` for debugging purposes and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Please explain what kind of data you would put in that `MemoryStream`? The uncompressed data? If the data was not compressed in the first place, there would be no problem. So yes, then the problem goes "away". But the data is compressed, so the `ZlibStream` is required.

Comment: Yes, the same uncompressed data which goes into and out of ZlibStream. As far as I understand your question, you use ZlibStream on both sending and receiving side. Apart from that, compression is transparent, so instead of ZlibStream for testing purpose you could use any stream, e.g. CryptoStream or MemoryStream. If you did that, and everything works without blocks, I'd try some other implementations of ZlibStream, e.g. [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Err.. not DotNetZip as you're already using it. Perhaps, [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) instead.

Comment: I don't think I can use DeflateStream, since Zlib is a wrapper around that, and my stream is exactly that; a Zlib stream. I do not have the possibility to modifying the other end.

Comment: The fact that you cannot control the receiving end makes that irrelevant, but to clarify: I referred to `DeflateStream` from .NET `System.IO.Compression`, which is a different from `Ionic.Zlib` implementation.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at that particular class in `System.IO.Compression`. It doesn't work directly, because the main compressed stream is a Zlib stream.

Answer (score 2):

Zlib, as well as other compression algorithms, operates with blocks of data. It bufferes some data from the source stream and then tries to compress it.

If you put in the ZlibStream data that is less than buffer size, nothing will actually come out of ZlibStream right away. Your data will be sitting there until buffer fills. To get that data compressed, flushing your original stream, and probably even compressed stream, would not be enough.

All your readInts should receive the right data if serve closes the ZlibStream.

If you want to receive packets from server in real-time, try completely compressing the packets first and then send them through the network stream.

Comment: All packets are compressed and flushed in the stream, as shown here: `78 5E <bytes of packet> 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 FF FF <bytes of another packet> 00 00 FF FF 00 00 00 FF FF <bytes of another packet> etc..` Why exactly is that not enough?

Comment: @alex, doesn't calling `Flush` on `ZlibStream` finishes the current compression buffer and sends compressed data to the raw output stream?

Comment: @Angelo, do you set `FlushMode` on your ZLibStream to `FlushType.Sync` or `FlushType.Full`?

Comment: I set it to `FlushType.Full`.

Comment: @AngeloGeels, have you tried closing the stream instead of flushing? Did it help?

Comment: The stream doesn't close, it's a continuous stream that is flushed every packet. Why would I close it? That shouldn't be required.

Comment: @AngeloGeels, just for testing, to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: As I've written before, I don't have the ability to modify the other end.

Answer (score 2):

First, you say

> "Every read operation on the ZlibStream blocks until the packet is
>   repeated by the other end."

That means that there's a read on your server... E.g. the pattern should be like...

```
Client: Connects to server, asks for data
Server: Sends packet
Client: Reads packet
Client: Sends same packet back
Server: Reads Packet
Server: Sends new packet?
```

If that's the case, the server will always block since you're `ReadInt32()`ing 3 times. Are you positive the other int packets are sent by your server?

---

Second, I wouldn't use ZlibStream to read directly from a network socket. I'd read in the raw data from the network stream, buffer it, and have another method fire when data was in the buffer that decompressed it...
In psuedocode:

```
byte[] compressedDataBuffer
bool canReadFromBuffer = false;
ASYNC:
    while(true):
        get current network stream, see if there's data
        if it has data:
            add networkStream's current data to compressedDataBuffer
            lock:
                if compressedDataBuffer has new data/has enough data
                    canReadFromBuffer = true
                else
                    canReadFromBuffer = false
        else:
            sleep(0); //yield cycles
SYNC:
    while(true):
        if canReadFromBuffer:
            create a memory stream of compressedDataBuffer
            create a zlibstream around that memory stream
            perform operations on the zlibstream that are required.
```